# Há alguma maneira de um formulário herdar do _Layout.cshtml em c#?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Eu estou a desenvolver um website em `asp.net c#`, tenho uma página de contato que contém um formulário para o utilizador preencher e enviar caso queira enviar um e-mail.

Queria que a página desse formulário herdasse as propriedades das restantes páginas do site, como por exemplo o menu e o rodapé.

Há alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, M. Carreira,

A arquivo **_Layout.cshtml** , é aonde fica o Layout padrão para suas views. Quando você cria um projeto no Visual Studio do tipo Asp.Net MVC, ele cria automaticamente esse arquivo. Nele contém a barra de navegação que fica na parte de cima da página, com um alguns links como, Home, About e Contacte o rodapé também.

Para que todas as suas Views herdem esse layout contido no **_Layout.cshtml** automaticamente, você deve verificar se o arquivo ***ViewStart.cshtml*** ( que tica dentro da pasta Views do seu projeto) está dessa forma:

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```

Caso esteja, tudo que estiver no**_Layout.cshtml** será aplicado para todas as suas views, sem necessidade de você repetir código página por página;.

Se você quiser alterar o rodapé ou o menu de cima, basta alterar o arquivo **_Layout.cshtml**  que todas as modificações serão aplicadas a todas as suas Views, inclusive a sua página de contato.

Caso tenha alguma dificuldade, fala comigo :D

Comment: Isso já eu sei caro colega! Mas tal como eu disse, a minha página de contacto contém um formulário, logo é uma Web Form e não uma View. Se fosse uma View não estava a colocar esta questão :)

Answer (score 0):

já tentou utilizar ou @rendersection?
Na página principal, a qual deseja integrar os forms, insira:

```
 `@Rendersection("@nomedaestrutura", bool)`
```

na página a qual deseja puxar as infos:

```
@Section nomedaestrutura{
(form)
(input)
(/forms)
}
```

e troque os parentes pelos sinais de menor e maior para abrir e fechar as tags HTML.